# Slim down and/or understand the Eclipse files in a Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, ant

The files residing in .settings in a **Dynamic Web Project** are:

```
.settings/
|-- org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
|-- org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.core.prefs
|-- org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ejb.annotations.xdoclet.prefs
|-- org.eclipse.wst.common.component
|-- org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
|-- org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.container
|-- org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.name
`-- org.eclipse.wst.validation.prefs
```

The above file list is pretty much a clean new Dynamic Web Project, except that I'm using the IvyDE plug in, but I think it only affects the .classpath file.

**How do I learn more about these files? I'm wondering if I can get rid of any of them without loosing something important?** Finding this information at Eclipse.org was not very easy, a link or an explanation would be very welcome.

I'm trying to learn more about these files as I want to slim down the Eclipse files as much as possible before I check them into version control.

In case it helps I list the above files and their contents:

**org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs:**

```
#Mon Jan 26 03:01:22 CET 2009
eclipse.preferences.version=1
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.5
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.5
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.assertIdentifier=error
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.enumIdentifier=error
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.5
```

**org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.core.prefs:**

```
#Mon Jan 26 03:01:22 CET 2009
classpath.helper/org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER\:\:org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType\:\:java-6-sun-1.6.0.07/owners=jst.java\:5.0
eclipse.preferences.version=1
```

**org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ejb.annotations.xdoclet.prefs:**

```
#Mon Jan 26 03:23:25 CET 2009
XDOCLETBUILDERACTIVE=false
XDOCLETHOME=
XDOCLETUSEGLOBAL=false
XDOCLETVERSION=1.2.1
eclipse.preferences.version=1
```

**org.eclipse.wst.common.component:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
    <wb-module deploy-name="webcookie">
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/main/webapp"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/java"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/test/java"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/resources"/>
        <property name="context-root" value="webcookie"/>
        <property name="java-output-path"/>
    </wb-module>
</project-modules>
```

**org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faceted-project>
  <fixed facet="jst.java"/>
  <fixed facet="jst.web"/>
  <installed facet="jst.java" version="5.0"/>
  <installed facet="jst.web" version="2.5"/>
</faceted-project>
```

**org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.container:**

```
org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.l
```

**org.eclipse.wst.validation.prefs:**

```
#Mon Jan 26 03:31:54 CET 2009
DELEGATES_PREFERENCE=delegateValidatorList
USER_BUILD_PREFERENCE=enabledBuildValidatorListorg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.classpathdep.ClasspathDependencyValidator;org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.ModuleCoreValidator;org.eclipse.wst.wsi.ui.internal.WSIMessageValidator;
USER_MANUAL_PREFERENCE=enaunching.baseBrowserLibrary
```

**org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.name:**

```
Window
```

**org.eclipse.wst.validation.prefs:**

```
#Mon Jan 26 03:31:54 CET 2009
DELEGATES_PREFERENCE=delegateValidatorList
USER_BUILD_PREFERENCE=enabledBuildValidatorListorg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.classpathdep.ClasspathDependencyValidator;org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.ModuleCoreValidator;org.eclipse.wst.wsi.ui.internal.WSIMessageValidator;
USER_MANUAL_PREFERENCE=enabledManualValidatorListorg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.classpathdep.ClasspathDependencyValidator;org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.ModuleCoreValidator;org.eclipse.wst.wsi.ui.internal.WSIMessageValidator;
USER_PREFERENCE=overrideGlobalPreferencesfalse
eclipse.preferences.version=1
override=false
suspend=false
vf.version=3
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's see:

- `org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` is really important and control how you compile your java project.
- `org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.core.prefs` adds a **[Facet](http://org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml)**, basically a way to introduce functionality to projects in Eclipse, therefore a project can have one or more facets (ie. it could be a Java project and a EJB project). See [here for illustration](http://servicemix.apache.org/extending-eclipse-wtp-to-support-jbi.html) (search the word 'Facet')
- `org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ejb.annotations.xdoclet.prefs` is a way to [Configuring XDoclet annotation support](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jst.ejb.doc.user/topics/txdocletconf.html)
- `org.eclipse.wst.common.component` is relate to the [deployment structure](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.webtools/msg17655.html).
- `org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml` is used to [Specifying target servers for J2EE projects](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user/topics/tjtargetserver.html)
- `org.eclipse.wst.validation.prefs` refers to [Wst validation](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/wst/components/validation/ValidationOverview.html)
- `org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.container/name` [as explained here](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.webtools.atf/msg00430.html), is a configuration for JSDT part:

  > By default, plain javascript files (.js) inherit members from object Global. HTML files contained in a static/dynamic web project inherit members from object Window.
  >   So if your context is a plain javaScript file it will appear that only Window.window or Window.alert(..) is valid since none of the Window members are inherited. What you really want is to inherit this field + method from an instance of the Window object.
  >   **,**
  >   The JSDT supports a configurable super type at the project level. Each .js or .html file within a project inherits all the fields and methods from the projects super type. By default the type is Global for standalone JavaScript projects and Window for Static/Dynamic Web Projects.
  >   **,**
  >   You can change the super type for a project from the JavaScript Include Path properties page from Object Global to Object Window to achieve the results you desire... On the Global Order/SuperType page change the Super Type to Window in the ECMA library.

Comment: the link for deployment structure http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=88 is not working any more, can you please update this. Seems interesting.

Comment: @Jeremy: it was interesting, but I am unable to understand how to translate the old `dev.eclipse.org/newslists` URL into a new `www.eclipse.org/forum` one...

Comment: do you know somehow the old heading of the article/forum post?

Comment: @Jeremy: sadly no. And Wayback won't work: http://web.archive.org/web/20110826111942/http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.webtools/msg17655.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use and trust the "Dependencies" tab in the MANIFEST.MF. After working about a year with Eclipse plugins only i would not try to find out which eclipse plugin dependency is necessary or not.

When you miss a plugin which is needed at runtime, you get exceptions which are not very useful and solutions are not obvious.

The MANIFEST actions "Find unused dependencies" should selected every time you refactor your code. It also helps to check the classes, eclipse will create, when you generate  complete new plugin from scratch. The eclipse plugins are not good documented, so i would use the actions which are offered and dont spend so many times to understand them all.

If you realy want to find out which plugins are used, when you create a plugin from scratch, you can delete some extend declarations or variables and press the "Find unused dependencies" action to see, which plugin is for a call.